# CKEditor 5 remove extra <p> tags when paste content from word

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ckeditor, ckeditor5

When I copy paste content from word to CKEditor I get extra spaces (line breaks) which is not in the original document, its caused by `<p><br>&nbsp;</p>` tag which is been added by CKEditor while pasting. How can I remove this tag on paste?
Do we have an event to capture the content on paste and modify the content before saving?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can control the paste event on ckeditor with this:

```
editor.on('paste', function(evt) {});
```

but before that your problem probably is your editor is on p mode to change it to br you need to add this on the config:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

if all of this fail you can clean the tags before paste something like this:

```
editor.on('paste', function(evt) {
// cancel paste
evt.stop();

// get text of clipboard
var text = evt.data.dataValue;

// clean html tags
var dom = document.createElement("div");
dom.innerHTML = text;
plain_text=dom.innerText;


editor.insertText(plain_text);
});
```